# Jasmine, one test, multiple ajax requests ( error: ajax has already been spied upon )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine

I have a Jasmine 2.0.2 test that triggers an ajax request, but each time the request is fired, the mock ajax return should be a specific return value.

```
  var setUpDeleteEventInAjax = function(spyEvent, idToReturn){
    var spy;
    spy = jasmine.createSpy('ajax');
    spyAjaxEvent = spyOnEvent(spyEvent, 'click');
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (param) {
      return {
        id: idToReturn,  // here I am trying to return a defined value
        status: true
      };
    });
    spyAjaxEvent.reset();  //  this should reset all ajax evetns
  };

...
beforeEach(function(){...})
afterEach(function(){...})
...

it('Deleting all the addresses should reveal the form', function () {

    setUpDeleteEventInAjax('#delete',52670);
    $('#delete').click();
    expect($('.address-item').length).toEqual(4);

    setUpDeleteEventInAjax('#delete-2',52671);
    $('#delete-2').click();
    expect($('.address-item').length).toEqual(2);

    setUpDeleteEventInAjax('#delete-3',52672);
    $('#delete-3').click();
    expect($('.address-item').length).toEqual(0);

  });
...
```

After the delete button is clicked ( delete,delete-2,delete-3 ) the total length address-items is reduced by 2, ( when the return from the server responds with a number - this is the crux of the mock).

However, jasmine complains that "ajax has already been spied upon." Is there a way to return a new value from the ajax mock in order to fulfill the test?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the way I went about it was over engineered. Just needed a closure. Did not need my custom `setUpDeleteEventInAjax` function

```
  it('Deleting all the addresses should reveal the form', function () {
    var responses = [52670, 52671, 52672];
    var ajaxResponses = function () {
      return {
        status: true,
        id: responses.shift()
      }
    };
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(ajaxResponses);

    $('#delete').click();
    expect($('.address-item').length).toEqual(4);

    $('#delete-2').click();
    expect($('.address-item').length).toEqual(2);
    expect($('.address-book')).toHaveClass('single-address');

    $('#delete-3').click();
    expect($('.address-item').length).toEqual(0);

  });
```

Comment: BTW, if you set up your responder function to `return { status: true, id: responses.shift() };` you don't need that `callCount` variable.